# Program takes a list of pair and return it ordered from small to big

Tags: haskell

so I wrote this program where it takes a key value list and return the pair with the biggest value, now i want the program to return the the original list but organized as the smallest value at the first and then the biggest at the last for example **[(4,3) , (2,10), (2,1)] -> it returns [(2,1) , (4,3), (2,10)]**

```
vector :: Ord a => [(t, a)] -> (t, a)
vector (x:xs) = maxTail x xs
  where maxTail currentMax [] = currentMax
        maxTail (m, n) (p:ps)
          | n < (snd p) = maxTail p ps
          | otherwise = maxTail (m, n) ps
```

I tried to do this

```
vec xs = [ vector tt | tt <- xs]
```

but does not work because vector function  brings back list of lists of pair and vector function takes lists of pair.

how can I modify it to do what I want it to do

---

@leftaroundabout helped with this function

```
import Data.List (sortOn)

sortOnSnd :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
sortOnSnd = sortOn snd
```

now if there was two values that equal each other I want the program to order it according to the key for example **[(42,3), (3,3), (4,1)] -> [(4,1), (3,3), (42,3)]**
Here what I did

```
import Data.List (sortOn)

sortOnSnd :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
sortOnSnd = sortOn snd 
if sortOn snd == sortOn snd then sortOn fst
```

it gives error in the main IO function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *what ever gave you the idea* that it would be a good idea to call this function “vector”?? Let's make it instead

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.List (comparing)

maximumOnSnd :: Ord a => [(t, a)] -> (t, a)
maximumOnSnd = maximumBy $ comparing snd
```

Now, you *could* use that for implementing [a sorting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), but it will be absurdly inefficient – not just because it's an *O* (*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, also because it requires some unnecessary extra list traversals. In particular, it's not enough to just *find* the highest element, you actually need to *extract* it. One possibility (both inefficient and unreliable) is to filter out the one you found:

```
extrMaximumOnSnd :: (Ord a, Eq t) => [(t, a)] -> ((t, a), [(t, a)])
extrMaximumOnSnd l = (maxMember, filter (/=maxMember) l)
 where maxMember = maximumOnSnd l
```

Given that, you can then recursively implement the selection sort:

```
sortOnSnd :: (Ord a, Eq t) => [(t, a)] -> [(t, a)]
sortOnSnd [] = []
sortOnSnd l = case extrMaximumOnSnd l of
     (maxMember, others) -> sortOnSnd ++ [maxMember]
```

But again, keep in mind that this is very inefficient, less general then it should be (`Eq t` constraint) and unreliable, in particular when the list contains duplicate elements.

A much better solution is

```
import Data.List (sortOn)

sortOnSnd :: Ord a => [(t, a)] -> [(t, a)]
sortOnSnd = sortOn snd
```

Comment: Thank you, now there is a case where, if two values are the same.. then they are ordered as the key, for example [(4,3), (2,3),(10,5)] -> [(2,3), (4,3),(10,5)].  I add to the last function this line but it gives me an error in the main :: IO
         where if sortOn snd == sortOn snd then sortOn fst

Comment: Try `sortOn swap`. No need to make an explicit case distinction.

Comment: `comparing` is in Data.Ord